# SSH Login Via Keyfile With No Local Password

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have my remote SSH setup with my public key so I can login with it. This is great; however, I still have to type the password for my private key file. How can I login using the keyfile and no password for the keyfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your keypair with passphrase. And it prompts you to enter passphrase each time. Either create new keypair (and copy public key to remote system again) without a passphrase or look at ssh-agent how to enter passphrase just once.